# How to position separate html tables to look like a single table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 2 logically separate tables: `.table-a` and `.table-b`. I would like to have 2 different `table` HTML elements for each of them.

But I would like to position them side by side with some margin/visual components in between.

However, I would like to position them so that they look like 1 table (rows from table-a **visually** match rows from table-b) regardless of the content in both table cells. But I do not want to merge them in a single table as they are not logically the same table and I would also like to position some other elements in between.

```html
<div class="container">
        <table class=“table-a”>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Table A column</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Table A row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Table A row 1</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class=“table-b”>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Table B column</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Table B row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Table B row 1</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: just add css `display:inline`

Comment: `[class*="table-"] { display: inline-table; }` to begin with but then there's no sure and safe way to align rows: height property on cells is equivalent to min-height on block elements and fixed heights on cells displayed as grid items or flex items won't allow multiline content and probably fail on zoom text, which partially sighted people rely on heavily.

Comment: @Nas woking example as ChintuYadavSara said [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav1330/buwd82e0/3/)

Comment: OP: how should the tables behave if one table has more rows than the other? Or if content in one cell causes a line wrap in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following way you can achieve it. Also keep it mind to keep the row inline with two different table you should not allow in one table multi line or other table single line so you need must add following CSS in table cells:

```
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
 display:flex;
}
.table-a,
.table-b {
 display:inline-block;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.table-b {
 margin-left:-1px;
}
.table-a th,
.table-a td,
.table-b th,
.table-b td {
 border:1px solid #ddd;
 padding:4px;
 vertical-align:top;
 white-space:nowrap;
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table-a">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table A column</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table A row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table A row 1</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table-b">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table B column</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table B row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table B row 1</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't know if OP has multiple lines in a cell. If so, there is a problem, vertically-speaking. Check for comments in my answer.

Comment: @FonzTech I just showed a way and I think then it is not possible only by CSS so far. Then you should take help by javascript.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Our answers are better than nothing. I think when you have to do "visually-sensible" things like this in JavaScript, just join the tables and let the browser do the work (find another solution). The code you have to write to do this without joining tables is too much for this "simple" thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your CSS styling, but I'm trying to give an answer.
Below there is the code which displays both tables side by side:

```
<style>
.table-a, .table-b {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-table;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table-a">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table A column</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table A row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table A row 1</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><!--
    --><table class="table-b">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table B column</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table B row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table B row 1</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The trick is to set your tables to be `inline`, so they can rest with other elements on the same line. So you have to set the `display` property of that element. There is a `inline-table` value, ideal for tables, because the default value is `table` (But remember, we want the element to be inline).

Have a look here for further explanation on the `display` property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

But how can we achieve no spacing between tables?
There are some "tricks" to do this.
I put comments between the close tag of the first table and the open tag of the second table. This is remove the whitespace visually.

Now you will see "visually-joined" tables. You may see "double border" between tables. You have to adjust this yourself with CSS styling, because I don't know what you want to achieve specifically, but I think I have answered your question.

Just let me know in the comments.

EDIT: As said in the comments, my solution does not solve how to achieve same line height for all the tables. Anyway, my answer was too complex for a comment. I hope for no downvote :(

Comment: OP also want rows to be aligned: each row should start and end at the same position on Y axis.

Comment: add vertical-align:top;

Comment: Lalji, styling should be done by OP. I answered on how to achieve side-by-side table only. If you think that top-aligning would solve row origin on Y axis, the answer is yes, but does not solve the height problem, because there is nothing to say how the two table should be joined. I think OP should apply table styling to the element hierarchy, starting with "container", if he wants to keep separate tables. Remember that height is determined by width and content.

Answer (score 0):

use this style

`.container{
  display: inline-flex;
}`